# Fast way to check 2000 checkboxes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a webpage with a couple thousand checkboxes on it, and would like to add a "Check all" feature. Unfortunately, my current implementation hangs Google Chrome for at least five seconds.

Here is what I have tried (using jQuery):

```
$('input').attr('checked', true); // as well as...
$('input').click();
```

I believe that the actual Javascript runs fast, however the browser might be having trouble rendering all the updates so quickly. Could I be doing something else?

Here is a simplified example: https://www.msu.edu/~weinjare/checkboxes.html

I've also ran the Profiler built-in to Chrome and got these results:
[image: Profiler results]

Comment: Tab + Spacebar would work just fine...  =]

Comment: I think your first problem is the fact that there are so many checkboxes on screen.  I know this aint what you want to hear but I'd be considering a rethink of the UI.

Comment: Oddly, much faster in firefox.

Comment: @griegs, I agree, but I have to say, that simplified example page is rather mesmerising :)

Comment: I don't think jQuery is the problem, using native dom calls, you experience a similar delay: `[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input'), 0).forEach(function (x) { x.checked = false; });`

Comment: I tried putting each checkbox on a new line so only a few dozen were on the screen at one time. It didn't help the speed. I don't know if Chrome would render off screen checkboxes, but it still is interesting.

Comment: One more thing that is interesting, is that if the checkboxes are currently unchecked, and you run `[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input'), 0).forEach(function (x) { x.checked = false; });` then it executes instantly. Toggling the state of the checkbox is the real killer here.

Comment: Do you have any `change` event handlers on these checkboxes?

Comment: @Ates: Nope, just what you see in the simplified example.

Comment: @Box9, it's like one of those pictures that if you stare at it long enough you'll see a ship.

Comment: @pst, I think that my profile above shows that it is not the selector. The `jQuery.jQuery` function call is what executes the selector, whereas the `attr` function acts upon that collection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Accessing the DOM attributes directly *may* be faster, though my guess is that it won't be significantly faster:

```
var els = $('input');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].checked = true;
}
```

But as you say, the biggest problem is probably the rendering. You could try batching the execution within setIntervals of 0 milliseconds. This won't speed anything up, but at least will stop the "hanging":

```
var els = $('input'), i = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    var batchLen = i + 100 > els.length ? els.length : i + 100;
    for (; i < batchLen; i++) {
        els[i].checked = true;
    }
    if (i === els.length) clearInterval(interval);
}, 0);
```

Comment: The setInterval trick does allow the UI to draw the progress. This is interesting.

Comment: i've seen it in one of jquery's book, and it really impress, Jquery object save in var make code be efficient and setInterval to stop script in specific time... nice tips

Answer (score 1):

Practical implementation of this solution aside Chrome seems to be much faster if you empty the checkbox container first, generate the lot as a string with the attribute checked and append back to DOM. So in your example it would be (just need to surround the checkboxes with a div with id boxes)

```
<script> 
  var checkAll = function() {
  html ="";
   $("#boxes").empty();
   for (i=0;i<2000;i++) {
   html+="<input type=checkbox checked>";
  }
  $("#boxes").append(html);
   return false;}
  var uncheckAll = function() { html ="";
   $("#boxes").empty();
   for (i=0;i<2000;i++) {
   html+="<input type=checkbox>";
  }
  $("#boxes").append(html);
   return false;};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It takes about 0.5 seconds with Firefox. Are you sure the problem is Google Chrome?

Comment: yeah, it is neary instantaneous in Opera.

Comment: It is interesting... I am seeing the fast speeds in Firefox as well.

Answer (score 0):

DOM operations are really slow as you have already noticed... Something that you can do to avoid hogging the browser is to use the handy "setTimeout" function which lets you delay the execution of the function. This way you return the thread to the browser to make it responsive...

```
  var checkAll = function() {
    var inputs = $('input');
    var n = inputs.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      (function(i){
        setTimeout(function(){
          $(inputs.get(i)).attr('checked', true);
        },0);
      })(i);
    }
    return false;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a big fan of chrome. I tried in a older version of chrome & jquery that I have.

Official Build 2200
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.2.149.30 Safari/525.13

jQuery 1.4.2

The checkboxes are checked in 0.5 sec. What version are you using?

Answer (score -4):

try:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: This didn't provide any improvement, as it is nearly identical to the code I was already using.

Comment: it actually could make a difference depending on whats in your page. This just makes sure that there is no waste if there are other input types in the page,

Comment: this won't speedup anything.